# Problema com caracter especial "ç" no javascript

Tags: javascript, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Tenho um switch case para verificar o mês e tive que adicionar um hexcode para o mês de Março não ficar com problema no caracter "ç".

A string de Março estava ficando assim: Mar�o

Uma das maneiras de resolver o problema seria colocando a tag  no html, porém o código é javascript puro e não consigo setar essa tag.

Coloquei o hexcode, funcionou perfeitamente, porém gostaria de saber qual é a melhor maneira de fazer isso.

Comment: Mas você está exibindo esse valor no HTML ou no console? Se for no HTML, não tem porque não colocar a tag referente ao *charset*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar uma sequência de escape UNICODE `\u` para representar o `ç` e o `Ç`:

`\u00e7` é equivalente ao `ç` (minúsculo)

`\u00c7` é equivalente ao `Ç` (maiúsculo)

Por exemplo:

```js
alert('mar\u00e7o'); 
alert('MAR\u00c7O');
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você está exibindo coisas que não são trazidas do banco de dados pode utilizar esta `tag` no seu arquivo HTML, `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` Ou se o caso é trazer dados do banco de dados com acentuação irá ter que criar uma função para isso a fim de trocar valores que possam apareçer desta forma

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<form method="POST" name="alimento">
   <select>
      <option selected>Feij&atilde;o</option>
      <option>Pa&ccedil;oca</option>
   </select>
</form>

<?php
   $alimento = utf8_decode(($_POST['alimento']));
   echo $alimento;
?>
```

Tendo como resultado do select => `Paçoca e Feijão`

Comment: vou consertar o código

Answer (score -1):

Caso não queira usar o hexcode pode tentar usar ussa função para dar encode no "ç"... não acho viável sempre que tiver um caractere especial ter que procurar o hexcode dele:

[UTF8_encode](http://locutus.io/php/xml/utf8_encode/)